# FancyBox jQuery when closing modal image parent image disappear

Tags: modal-dialog, fancybox

I have little problem with fancybox jquery library.

when I use this simple line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

It's shows modal image Ok, but when I click on Close then original clicked image on parent page disappear ?

I could use this sample of code to reload original page image after clicking close button,but reloading is not good option.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            afterClose : function() {location.reload();return;}
        });​
    });
```

My question is how to prevent that my original clicked image does not disappear after I close modal image ?

Comment: You also may need to show your html code ... most likely you are applying fancybox to the `<img>` tag rather than the anchor `<a>` tag. What version of fancybox btw?

Comment: Hi JFK,  here are html:        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phPreview" runat="server">        
                <asp:Image class="fancybox" ID="imgPreview" runat="server" />
            </asp:PlaceHolder>        yes I use it on img tag.   I use latest version v2.1.1 of fancybox.

Comment: I was try to surround img tag with a tag: <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phPreview" runat="server">     
            <a href = "#" class="fancybox" >   
                <asp:Image  ID="imgPreview" runat="server" />                   
            </a>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>                Then I got message box with :  "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later".

Comment: you have to apply the `class="fancybox"` to the `<a>` tag and the `href` should point to the image you want to open with fancybox

Comment: Thanks JFK it works on my test project ... now need to incorporate in real project... thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to apply the class="fancybox" to the `<a>` tag and the `href` should point to the image you want to open with fancybox – JFK